# Rest service working in Postman but not in Python IDE (Anaconda)

Tags: python, rest, proxy

I am trying to invoke a rest service through Jupyter. It is failing with "Tunnel connection failed: 404 Not found". But the same works with Postman.

Please let me know how to handle this scenario in Jupyter.

Following things are configured as environment variables.
HTTP_Proxy = :
HTTPS_Proxy = :

Following is my rest call.

```
import requests

url = "https://<Url>"

payload = "{\"start\":0,\"end\":1461927918213,\"tags\":[{\"name\":\"OfflineObjects.Demo.Dynamic.Sambit.Float\"}]}"
headers = {
    'content-type': "application/json",
    'zone-id': "a698eb6c-fc46-452c-a000-50290ba5bf84",
    'authorization': "bearer <token>",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'postman-token': "1fe11475-8017-bbb0-8b19-beb1eadafc60"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

I am getting the following exception.

> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, **response_kw)
>       553             if is_new_proxy_conn:
>   --> 554                 self._prepare_proxy(conn)
>       555
>
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _prepare_proxy(self, conn)
>       749 
>   --> 750         conn.connect()
>       751
>
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py in connect(self)
>       229             # self._tunnel_host below.
>   --> 230             self._tunnel()
>       231             # Mark this connection as not reusable
>
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _tunnel(self)
>       808             raise OSError("Tunnel connection failed: %d %s" % (code,
>   --> 809                                                                message.strip()))
>       810         while True:
>
> OSError: Tunnel connection failed: 404 Not found
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
>   C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
>       375                     retries=self.max_retries,
>   --> 376                     timeout=timeout
>       377                 )
>
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, **response_kw)
>       608             retries = retries.increment(method, url, error=e, _pool=self,
>   --> 609                                         _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
>       610             retries.sleep()
>
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
>       272         if new_retry.is_exhausted():
>   --> 273             raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
>       274
>
> MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='url', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/datapoints (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 404 Not found',)))

Thanks.